# Custom encryption trait breaks carbon functionality and gives error: The payload is invalid

Tags: laravel, encryption, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I'm using a custom encryption trait on my Journal model. I didn't create this code and vaguely understand how it works, [but the original code can be found here on this Laracast forum post.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/encrypting-model-data)

**Encryption.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
trait Encryptable
{
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
            $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
            return $value;
        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
            $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

**Journal.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Journal extends Model
{
    use Encryptable;

    protected $encryptable = [
        'content'
    ];
    protected $fillable = ['content','user_id'];

}
```

I'm getting two problems:

1. > Call to a member function toRfc822String() on null (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thought-records/resources/views/journal/index.blade.php)
2. When I remove `toRfc822String()` from my blade file it throws this error: The payload is invalid.

Here is the index.blade.php

```
<div class="card-body">
    @if($entries->isEmpty())
        <p>There is nothing here!</p>
    @else
        @foreach($entries as $entry)
            <a href="/entry/{{$entry->id}}"><h3>{{ $entry->created_at }}</h3></a>
            <div v-html="markdown('{{ htmlentities($entry->content) }}')"> </div>
            <hr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getAttribute` method has to return something. Your method returns void. Every attribute you try to access via the dynamic property, `$model->attribute`, will be `null` because of this.

Comment: I edited the code to return the `$value` in the `getAttribute` method. I tried out retrieving the record in tinker and it unencrypted perfectly `$entry = App\Journal::where('id',14)->first();`

`$entry->content`


 but now I must still be returning a null value in blade because I'm getting the same payload exception. The problem with carbon seems fixed though.

Comment: You are probably hitting an `$entry` that doesn't have an encrypted value for `content` while you are iterating ... in tinker you are hitting one record which you know works

Comment: Ahh just found an entry that wasn't encrypted and that was the problem. Thanks a lot